# Reordering cell interactively with resized imageView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to be able to reorder cells in my collectionview but have the cell that is moving's image be scaled down to a smaller size for the duration of the reorder. I am able to get the cell to resize while moving but there is an issue when the cell crosses over another cell and attempts to reorder. At the moment the cell reaches another cell, it temporarily resizes back to normal size, causing a flickering when moving it around.

I have followed [this blog description](http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/) for using Apple's methods to interactively reorder cells in a UICollectionView. The methods I am using are listed under the "Reordering Items Interactively" section of [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview).

I have a UICollectionView subclass, a UICollectionViewCell subclass, and extensions for UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, and UICollectionViewDelegate.

The way I am resizing the cell is by adding a boolean to my cell's subclass that is set to false by default but true when beginning and updating cell movement, and back to false when ending or canceling. In my sizeForItem method for the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout extension, I am checking the boolean and returning a size accordingly.

It has been difficult to debug where the methods are getting the size to display when the cell's image returns to normal size for a split second, causing the flickering behavior, as each method is called many times to update the movement smoothly.

I am not married to resizing the cell in this way, if it is the cause of the issue, I'm just not sure how to resize it and prevent it from flickering when crossing over other cells in the collectionview.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

**UPDATE**
Some code samples.

I update the size of the bounds of imageView in beginInteractiveMovementForItem to shrink it initially. By the time the collectionview calls the update method, the size gets reset, but the cell gets its size from sizeForItem, below is my logic for that.

As a side note, I have also tried resizing the bounds of the cell itself in beginInteractiveMovement in addition to the imageView's bounds, but it had no effect so I removed that.

Here's how I'm handling resizing the imageView:

In the collection view's parent:

```
@objc func handleLongGesture(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch(sender.state) {
    case .began:
        let location = sender.location(in: self.collectionView)
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: location) else {
            return
        }
        guard let dragCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: selectedIndexPath) as? ActivityPhotoGalleryCell else { return }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.17, animations: {
            dragCell.center = location
        })
        collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
    case .changed:
        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(sender.location(in: sender.view))
    case .ended:
        collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

In the collection view subclass:

```
override func beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    guard let dragCell = cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCellObject else { return false }
    draggingCell = dragCell
    dragCell.isDragging = true
    return super.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: indexPath)
}
```

And here is my size for item logic:

```
var sizeForItem = CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCellObject

    if (cell?.isDragging ?? false) {
        sizeForItem.height *= 0.7
        sizeForItem.width *= 0.7
    }

    return sizeForItem
```

Comment: What happens when you put the scaling code in an animation block? (Are you using a transform to scale the cell?) Show a few essential slivers of code.

Comment: @meaning-matters The scaling code was in an animation block but I removed that as I was planning on prettying things up after getting basic functionality down, and wanted to ensure there was nothing fancy messing up the functionality.

Comment: @meaning-matters I'd like to correct my above comment, I had forgotten the initial shrinking was handled in the collection view's parent view controller. I added that method above.
Also, I removed the code scaling the imageView bounds in beginInteractiveMovement because it had no effect, since sizeForItem shrinks the moving cell anyway.